# Define a method in es6 class from a higher order function

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

I'm currently converting some es5 javascript code to es6, converting old method declation to the class syntax.

```
Toto.prototype.titi = function() {}
// => 
class Toto {
    titi(){}
}
```

Problem is, some of the function are obtained from higher order function.

How should i convert something like this?

```
Toto.protype.titi = myFunctionFactory(function() {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using special new ES6 syntax, there's no way to change that. Just keep doing exactly as you're doing.

Looking [at the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions) shows that a method declared in a class must be a property name followed by an open parentheses, a variable number of arguments, a close parentheses, an open brace, a function body then a closing brace. No option for assigning from an expression.

> Syntax
>
> MethodDefinition[Yield] :
>
> PropertyName[?Yield] ( StrictFormalParameters ) { FunctionBody }